# How to execute a jQuery function on click of an anchor tag which is placed inside an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page in my application where I have an iframe loaded on the Page load.
The iframe displays a custom document which is created in our application. The iframe name is generated on the fly and the contents is loaded by a custom Javascript framework.
The document has two main vertical sections.
The first vertical section has page list which is displayed to the user so that user can navigate to nth page.

```
<iframe id="xyz15031550Iframe0" name="xyz15031550Iframe0" scrolling="no" src="/displaydocument/2339389/15031550?doc=100" style="height: 989px;" width="1277px" height="963px" frameborder="0">

<div class="containerFull">

<div class="allPages" id="allPages">

   <a class="pagenumber_001" href="/document/2339389/15031550">Page 1</a>
   <a class="pagenumber_002" href="/document/2339389/15031550">Page 2</a>
   <a class="pagenumber_003" href="/document/2339389/15031550">Page 3</a>

</div>
<div id="pagesArea">
  <div class="docPage" id="page_body_001">
    <div id="docPageSection-001-1">
      PAGE CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</iframe>
```

On page load, The iframe will be displaying the page 1.

By clicking the anchor tag, user can navigate to any page. On click of the anchor tag, the iframe is reloaded with the page details which is sent to back end.

Since some of the pages were bigger in width and user doesn't want the horizontal scroll to be present, I was adjusting the width of the iframe container and the two divs so to make them appear properly on the window.

`

```
<script src="adjust_doc_view.js"></script>
// the above script contains a jQuery function called updateView which basically 
// has css related jQuery statements.
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(updateView, 100); // timeout is used to wait for the iframe to load completely
});
```

`

The Issue which I am facing is the updateView is triggered only once on the page load. On all subsequent reload of Iframe, the updateView is not called. That is because I am not loading the whole page. I have other divs which are above the iframe which are constant. Let me know how to trigger updateView on every reload of iframe contents.

I tried adding the onclick function on anchor click event, but it works only once. I am not sure why.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    // use setTimeout() to execute
    // Setting the timeout to zero as no delay is experienced in this page.
    setTimeout(updateView, 0);

    jQuery("div[id^='artifactDiv']").find("iframe[id^='xyz']").contents().find("a[class^='pagenumber']").on('click', function() {
        setTimeout(updateView, 1000);
    });

    jQuery("div[id^='artifactDiv']").find("iframe[id^='xyz']").contents().find("div[id^='docPageSection']").on('load', function() {
        setTimeout(updateView, 1000);
    });
});
```

Please help me out here. Please correct me if I am doing something wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using jQuery `$.ajax` inside iframe to load new content?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, the custom javascript framework is using ajax and prototype.js as the base.

Comment: Can you add an ajaxSuccess global handler inside iframe?

Comment: @charlietfl I think that is not possible. we have couple of dependencies with the same file. Can we not avoid editing the Iframe creation part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding the `onload` attribute to your iframe and calling `updateView()` from there?

```
<iframe onload="setTimeout(function() { updateView(); }, 1000);" id="xyz15031550Iframe0" name="xyz15031550Iframe0" scrolling="no" src="/displaydocument/2339389/15031550?doc=100" style="height: 989px;" width="1277px" height="963px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Also, I noticed an extraneous closing `</iframe>` tag at the bottom of your page.  I would suggest removing it.

Comment: Thanks. I removed it.

Comment: thanks for saving my ___ . It is now triggering the updateView function every time the anchor is clicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) inside the iframe to trigger your update:

```
$(function() { 
  // iframe in main page   
  $('iframe').on('load', function() {

     updateView()// first load update

    // reference to window and document inside frame
    var win = this.contentWindow || this,
      doc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;

    // have to use iframe version of jQuery
    win.$(doc).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
      // fires every time an ajax request completes in iframe
      updateView()
    });
  });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/9MCAO8f1eoZgaAqYnRNT?p=preview)**</kbd>